# CalendarView horizontal lines disappear

Tags: android, calendarview

I created an activity with a CalendarView. When scrolling up and down, sometimes one of the grey horizontal lines disappears. See the following image for the lines I am talking about. What causes this?

[image]

view_calendar.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

ViewCalendar.java

```
public class ViewCalendar extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_calendar); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated xml code. Replace this code with your. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your "calender" one of the disappeared grey line shows that you are in that row. In that disappeared line one block shows grey pointing to the current date. Like in your "calender" that block `22`. You can see in the image provided in the below link.

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/calenderview-example/

Try this code in your xml-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I added a new screenshot I took myself. Look between week 7 and 8.

Comment: why you not try the code provided in the above link to find this?

Comment: Maybe you are using relative layout thats why you are facing problems.   Try linear layout instead of relative layout.

Comment: It didn't work. Is it some kind of bug of CalendarView? I noticed it only happens when I scroll up.